# How can i output string using Int 65H?

Tags: c++, c, systems-programming

I need to output some string using interrupt `Int 65` but its giving me error i am using **Turbo C++ 4.0 Windows 7 Windows 8 64Bit Version**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<BIOS.H>
#include<DOS.h>

void interrupt (*oldint65)( );
char st[80] = {"Hello World$"};
void interrupt newint65(void);

void main()
{
  oldint65 = getvect(0x65);
  setvect(0x65, newint65);
  geninterrupt (0x65);
  geninterrupt (0x65);
  geninterrupt (0x65);
  setvect(0x65, oldint65);
}

void interrupt newint65( )
{
  _AH = 0x09;
  _DX=(unsigned int)st;
  geninterrupt (0x21);
}
```

i have attached error image please help me where i am doing wrong

[image: Error image]

Comment: Copy and paste the full text of the error instead of an image that shows half the error.

Comment: how i can copy error ??? i don't know

Comment: Is there a way you can use a more recent compiler and the Windows 7 API?  I'm really amazed if the interrupt number is still valid with all these Windows versions.

Comment: in windows 7 its valid but i dont know its work in windows .8 or 10.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function definition is not matching/Clashing with the declaration..
Check:

- `void interrupt (*oldint65)();`
- `void interrupt *newint65(void);`

A single name interrupt Can't have 2 declarations..

Change in program should be as follows:

Declaration:

```
void interrupt(*newint65)(void);
```

Definition:

```
void interrupt(*newint65)( ) 
{ 
  _AH = 0x09; 
  _DX=(unsigned int)st; 
  geninterrupt (0x21); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:
Declaration:

```
void interrupt_newint65(void);
```

Definition:

```
 void interrupt_newint65( ) 
 { 
 _AH = 0x09; 
 _DX=(unsigned int)st; 
 geninterrupt (0x21); 
 }
```

Comment: please view remaining code also giving me error why??